# How to validate array of strings so that at least one is not null, in Yup

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a field which is a array of strings, and depending on this array's length I show inputs. If for example the length of arrray id 5 I show 5 inputs. However by default I have to show 3 inputs, and thats why my default values: `[null, null, null]`. Now what is the right way to do the validation so it checks the all values, and validate only if at least one is not `null`?

I know some answers, where they say: `yup.array().min(1)` is the solution, but in my case the initial value of the field is not an empty array. As I mentioned above there are null values, and I have to check every value of the array

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=yup+validate+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: The quote block formatting (lines prefixed with `>`) are intended for quoting text from others (including external sources). It is not intended as a form of emphasis. Please don't use it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `yup` but in plain javascript you could use `some`

```js
const invalidData = ['a', null, 'c']
const validData = [1, 2, 3]


const check = data => !data.some(v => v=== null)

console.log(invalidData, check(invalidData))
console.log(validData, check(validData))
```